# allow_url_fopen and allow_url_include with PHP require link

Tags: php, html

I have a website which requires a certain page on all the other pages that I have. My problem is that I can't require this page using `require` since the link url will change, take this senario as an example:
header.php:

```
<?php
  require('include/database.php');
?>
```

And then I have a file located at folder: woods/tree.php

If I want to connect to the database from my index file, there is no problem, but if I want to connect to it from tree.php, then the url will not be the correct on header.php anymore. And that leaves me a problem. I tried fixing this by using the entire url:

```
<?php
   require('http//www.example.com/include/database.php');
?>
```

My problem is now that I can't do that because of security issues with allow_url_fopen and allow_url_include. I will need to find another way to link to that page since I don't want to enable any of the php.ini settings because of its insecurity.

Is there another way for me to require the database so that all files in all folders can access it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This would't work with allow_url_include enabled either. The Server would process the PHP and you would only include the HTMK output of the included file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using an absolute path like:

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/include/database.php';
```

Comment: Yep that worked, thanks! Do you know if its always best to use `require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` instead of writing the actual root?

Comment: That is preferable in case you move your web application to different host, you won't have to change the root path in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing a problem where there is none. If I understood you correctly you have this example layout.

```
|
|-header.php
|-include/
| `-database.php
 `woods/
  `-tree.php
```

header.php:

```
include("include/database.php");
```

tree.php:

```
include("../header.php");
```

This will work, since the include always uses the path from the file where it is included. So `tree.php` will include `../header.php` which includes `include/database.php`. This will all work nicely.